# Cache dependency in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In the previous version it was possible to set a cache entry dependent of other cache entries.

In asp.net core, although the following text exists in the documentation

> You can configure cache entries to depend on other cache entries, the file system, or programmatic tokens, evicting the entry in response to changes. You can register a callback, which will run when a cache item is evicted.

I have no clue on how to implement this since there is no example in the documentation.

Comment: did you find an answer to this???

Answer (score 0):

The aspnet/Caching github project has some samples. A good file seems to be the
[MemoryCacheSample](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/samples/MemoryCacheSample/Program.cs).

To make the entry with `"key1"` expire after the entry with `"key2"` expires you create `"key1"` then

```
using (var entry = cache.CreateEntry("key1"))
{
    entry.Value = "value1";
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cache.Set("key2", "value2", new CancellationChangeToken(cts.Token));
}
```

Where `cache.Set` will create a new entry and call `AddExpirationToken` on the token we pass in.